# Read-only user query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, schema, oracle-12c

I have been asked to create a read only user in a Oracle database 12c. The read only user must have read only grants only to the objects of select schemas, which I created and handed over.

But now the request from the team is that the newly created read only user must have read only grants to even to all those new objects created by those select schemas.

How is this possible? Inputs please!

Comment: You mean, you would like some user to automatically get select privileges on tables of some other users as soon as they are created? I don't think that is possible, however, you could set up a scheduled job that will periodically check for new objects and grant select privileges on them to your user.

Comment: and can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: Google: dbms_scheduler (for setting up a scheduled job), dba_tab_privs and dba_tables (to find out who has which privileges).

Comment: That's fine.. But how do you check if new objects are created using scheduler is my question

Comment: You can just join dba_tab_privs and dba_tables to find out which tables are not yet granted to your user, and then grant select on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no, no, you should definitely not do this. It is the responsibility of the object creator to grant the necessary privileges. *(Although this is a common request, and it would be nice to finally have built-in support for this.)*

Since you are on 12c, forget `SELECT`, and grant `READ`. `SELECT` is not a read-only privilege. With `SELECT` granted, the grantee can run `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`, lock rows, and interfere. `READ` does not allow that.

What you asked is however still possible with some dirty tricks, using a DDL trigger, for example:

[How do I create a Oracle trigger that grants permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262539/how-do-i-create-a-oracle-trigger-that-grants-permissions)

Comment: nice! I did not know about read privilege in 12c..great info!!